# how to put 2 triangle in together css

Tags: html, css

I create 2 triangle with `CSS` and I want put inside together but I can't do it.

this is my code:

**Triangle.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Triangle</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.left
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid yellow;
}

.left .inside
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right: 18px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean by *put inside together* ?

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/HbMXB/1/)

**CSS**

```
.left {
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid yellow;
}

.left .inside {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px; left: 2px;
    width: 0px; height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right: 18px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I don't see it breaking. Of course, other elements will be visible by the black/blue shape remains intact. Like [**here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/HbMXB/2/) This is what happens to [**yours**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/N3vNU/1/)

Comment: Awesome!! You are a nice programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/N3vNU/).

**CSS:**

```
.left
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid yellow;
}

.left .inside
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right: 18px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

I only added `position:relative; top: -20px;` to `.left .inside` and it worked for me!

See more about positioning elements @ [w3schools - CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: It will break if Put put anything inside `.left` before `.inside`.

Comment: But he didn't mentioned that he is putting something inside that so I didn't gave him that type of solution!

Comment: I know he didn't but you never know ... I always that assume that OP's  never give full info, but that's just me :P. But yeah, I think its ok to assume he won't in this case, its just a shape.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

**Triangle.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Triangle</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="left inside"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.left
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid yellow;
}
.inside
{
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right: 18px solid black;
}
```

**See demo** http://jsfiddle.net/4fvwA/

Comment: Ummm ... You forgot to save your Fiddle.

Comment: Its will always stay on the same position. Not a good solution unless you exactly know what OP wants.

Comment: See Fiddle now, i saved it

Comment: Oh you changed the HTML too. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

you want this

```
.left .inside{
    margin-top:-18px;
    margin-left:2px;}
```

or this

```
.left .inside{
        margin-top:-18px;
        margin-left:22px;}
```